# What is wrong with my random number generator. (Python)

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

I am new to python. I was trying to make a random # generator but nothing works except for the else statement. I cannot tell what the issue is. Please Help!

```
import random
randomNum = random.randint(1, 10)
answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))

if (answer > randomNum) and (answer < randomNum):
    if (answer == randomNum + 1):
        print "Super Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum + 2):
        print "Pretty Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum + 3):
        print "Fairly Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum + 4):
        print "Not Really Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum + 5):
        print "Far"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum - 5):
        print "Far"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum - 4):
        print "Not Really Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum - 3):
        print "Fairly Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum - 2):
        print "Pretty Close"
        print randomNum
    elif (answer == randomNum - 1):
        print "Super Close"
        print randomNum
else:
    print "Good Job!"
    print randomNum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `if` statement logic is incorrect. `answer` cannot *at the same time* be both smaller and larger than `randomNum`, yet that is what your test asks for.

You want to use `or` instead of `and` there, if the `answer` value is larger *or* smaller than `randomNum`:

```
if (answer > randomNum) or (answer < randomNum):
```

or simply use `!=` to test for inequality:

```
if answer != randomNum:
```

Answer (score 0):

**I used this code for my random number generator and it works, I hope it helps**
You can change the highest and lowest random number you want to generate (0,20)

```
import random

maths_operator_list=['+','-','*']
maths_operator = random.choice(maths_operator_list)
number_one = random.randint(0,20)
number_two = random.randint(0,20)
correct_answer = 0

print(str(number_one), str(maths_operator), number_two)

if maths_operator == '+':
    correct_answer = number_one + number_two
elif maths_operator == '-':
    correct_answer = number_one - number_two
elif maths_operator == '*':
    correct_answer = number_one * number_two

print(correct_answer)
```